# Removing duplicate slashes in URL via .htaccess or PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, duplicates

I'm trying to remove duplicate slashes from URLs. The following .htaccess rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)//+(.*)$ $1/$2 [L,NC,R=301]
```

do NOT work for me on a URL such as the following:

```
http://www.mp7.org/?site=69.com\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
```

The .htaccess file

```
#### mod_rewrite in use
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
```

Comment: Why would a regexp that removes double slashes remove double backslashes?

Comment: Slashes and backslashes are different

Answer (score 0):

This rule won't work for *backslashes*. You must add a similar rule with backslashes

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)\\\\+(.*)$ $1\\$2 [L,R]
```

If you want to replace backslashes with (forward) slashes, use this rule instead

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)\\\\+(.*)$ $1/$2 [L,R]
```

And to remove all back-/slashes at the end of the request

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?)[/\\]+$ $1 [L,R]
```

and the same when it is a query string

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*=.*?)[/\\]+$
RewriteRule ^.*$ $0?%1 [R,L,QSA]
```

When everything works as you expect, you can change `R` to `R=301`.

*Never* test with `301` enabled, see this answer
[Tips for debugging .htaccess rewrite rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9204355/1741542)
for details.

Comment: RewriteRule ^(.+)\\\\+(.*)$ $1\$2 [L,R] ... Do not remove the backslashes

Comment: @user6509 Do you want to remove or replace the backslashes? I also forgot an additional backslash.

Comment: I want to remove completely ALL slashes or backslashes at the end of the URL

Comment: RewriteRule ^(.*)[/\\]+$ $1 [L,R] do NOT work. The URL is still accessible the way it was: http://www.mp7.org/?site=69.com\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

Comment: @user6509 I haven't realized, it is a query string.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of IIS server, and mainly almost certainly your site is urbanized in .Net .asp or . aspx You need to put into service one miniature script, when your server be given http or https demand it must Lcase(URL). If there are not a lot of pages, you can rename all within lowercase, modify all inner linking of WebPages to lowercase and after that appeal URL removal request in Google webmaster tools.

how to remove duplicate urls